# Будет ли написанное в Win7-32bit приложение работать в Win7-64bit?

Tags: windows, delphi

В каких случаях могут возникнуть затруднения? Пишу в Embarcadero Delphi XE.

Comment: А какая собственно разница, где приложение **написано**?

Comment: Хм, буду ли я прав, если скажу, что в случае объявления переменных не как (D)WORD/integer, а int32/int64 etc и без бибилотек все *должно* работать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что мучаетесь поддержка 64bit Application есть Embarcadero Delphi XE2
Миграция из под Embarcadero Delphi XE особых сложностей не вызывает.

Answer (score -1):

При программировании на **`Delphi`** проблем возникнуть не должно.

Comment: Да? То есть, по вашему, чеклист [\[`Embarcadero`\] **Converting 32 bit Delphi Applications to 64bit**][1] должен быть пустым?

[1]: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Converting_32-bit_Delphi_Applications_to_64-bit_Windows

Comment: Приложение же работать будет?

Comment: Что значит **будет работать?** Сделайте `SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SETTEXT, 0, Integer(@MyCharArray))` на 64 битах и посмотрим, как оно будет работать :)

Comment: А разве WOW64 не решает эту проблему? (для уже скомпилированного приложения)